# How to abort execution in GHCI?

Tags: haskell, ghci

When I launch

```
ghci> last [0..]
```

I can interrupt it with Ctrl+C.

However

```
ghci> last (repeat 0)
```

cannot be aborted with Ctrl+C. GHCI silently ignores the keystrokes.

How to abort this command in GHCI? Is it a bug?

Comment: I've also noticed this, so I'll be glad to see an answer, too. Perhaps it *is* a bug?

Comment: I fear that the latter command is never allocating memory. In such case, the GHC thread scheduler is (IIRC) unfair, and will never transfer control to other threads, or allow the async exception from Ctrl-C to be delivered. (To be honest, this used to be the case a long time ago, and I don't know if they worked around this somehow.)

Comment: I know the problem you're talking about, but at least for me (in GHC-7.10), Ctrl+C _does_ interrupt `last (repeat 0)`!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(Caveat lector: I use Linux, and run zsh on urxvt or gnome-terminal. If you use a different operating system, terminal, or shell, it's possible this will work differently for you.)

The way I usually handle this is to hit Ctrl+Z (which puts it in the background, pausing execution entirely as a side-effect) then kill the job. Usually this is `kill %1`, though you can run `jobs` to double-check.

You can also start a new terminal and do something like `killall -9 ghci`, but this has a much higher resource cost: you are spawning a few new processes, opening X connections, doing whatever it is your terminal does when it initializes itself, doing whatever it is your shell does when it initializes itself, etc. If you're in the situation I often find myself in -- ghci is swapping like crazy -- that just gives ghci more time to screw things up.

If you can predict this problem, and are compiling, you can use [`-fno-omit-yields`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--fomit-yields) to ask GHC to insert Ctrl+C checks even inside tight, non-allocating loops.

Answer (score 16):

You can quit GHCI using [`:quit`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/5.04.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html) command

```
Prelude> :quit
Leaving GHCi.
```

Or by pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> that [sends EOF signal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110240/why-does-ctrl-d-eof-exit-the-shell/).

If GHCI is busy you have no choice other than killing the process manually.

Comment: Why this is not an answer?

Comment: @gavrilikhin.d Because it relies on ghci being responsive. The entire question is about what to do when ghci is not responding normally.

Comment: @DanielWagner, yeah, i missed this part because I was looking for ways to simply exit ghci XD

Answer (score 4):

`Ctrl+Z` seems to leave the shell, but it doesn't entirely close the process.

For Example

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 
[4]+  Stopped                 ghci
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3160 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 3554 pts/1    00:00:21 emacs
 5602 pts/1    00:00:00 ghc
 5693 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

However if you do `Ctrl+D`

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.10.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> 
Leaving GHCi.
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 3160 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 3554 pts/1    00:00:21 emacs
 5870 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

So the proper way to close `haskell-shell` is to hit **`Ctrl+D`**.

*Note*: Tested on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS)

Comment: Ctrl+D will not close ghci while it is executing code. Ctrl+Z, on the other hand, sends a signal that can't be caught or handled by the receiving process, so will always work (for any process, not just ghci). You can clean up after the leftover process left behind by Ctrl+Z with `kill` or similar, as discussed in my answer.

Comment: Yeah.. `Ctrl+D` did not close my `ghci` when I ask it to compute `333^333^333` for me.