# How can I stop infinite evaluation in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

When I run something like:

```
Prelude> cycle "ab"
```

I can see an infinite printing of "ab". To stop it I just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. And it works.

When I run:

```
Prelude Data.List> nub $ cycle "ab"
```

I am not able to stop it.

**Question:**

- Why it so?
- How can I stop this operation?

**Update:**

```
 Ubuntu: version 18.10  
 GHCi:   version 8.2.2
```

Comment: I can reproduce this with GHCi 8.4.4 as described. `ghci` does not respond to repeated sigint or sigterm. Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188857/ghci-hangs-when-ctrlcing-from-infinite-loop-with-fbreak-on-exception-set)

Comment: You can open another terminal window, find the process ID of the ghci command that is running and kill it.

Comment: Also have a look at this: `CTRL+Z` should work on linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877019/how-to-abort-execution-in-ghci

Comment: @thatotherguy The similar question cannot get reproduced in GHC 8.0.1

Comment: Can you please add your GHCi version and operating system to the question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Great question! However, since [How to abort execution in GHCI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30877019/how-to-abort-execution-in-ghci) already focuses on your second part, let's not repeat that here. Instead, let's focus on the first.

> Why it so?

GHC optimizes loops aggressively. It optimizes them even further if there is no allocation [that it's even a known bug](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#bugs-in-ghc):

> #### 19.2.1. Bugs in GHC
>
> - GHC’s runtime system implements cooperative multitasking, with context switching potentially occurring only when a program allocates. **This means that programs that do not allocate may never context switch. This is especially true of programs using STM, which may deadlock after observing inconsistent state.** See [Trac #367](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/367) for further discussion. [emphasis mine]
>
>   If you are hit by this, you may want to compile the affected module with [`-fno-omit-yields`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--fomit-yields) (see [*-f*: platform-independent flags*](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#options-f)). This flag ensures that yield points are inserted at every function entrypoint (at the expense of a bit of performance).

If we check [`-fomit-yields`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-optimisation.html#ghc-flag--fomit-yields), we find:

> `-fomit-yields`
>
> Default: yield points enabled
>
> Tells GHC to omit heap checks when no allocation is being performed. While this improves binary sizes by about 5%, it also means
>   that threads run in tight non-allocating loops will not get preempted
>   in a timely fashion. **If it is important to always be able to interrupt
>   such threads, you should turn this optimization off. Consider also
>   recompiling all libraries with this optimization turned off, if you
>   need to guarantee interruptibility.** [emphasis mine]

`nub $ cycle "ab"` is a tight, non-allocating loop, although `last $ repeat 1` is an even more obvious non-allocating example.

The "yield points enabled" is misleading: `-fomit-yields` is enabled by default. As the standard library is compiled with `-fomit-yields`, **all functions in the standard library that lead to tight, non-allocating loops** may show that behaviour in GHCi, as you never recompile them.

We can verify that with the following program:

```
-- Test.hs
myLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
myLast [x]    = Just x
myLast (_:xs) = myLast xs
myLast _      = Nothing

main = print $ myLast $ repeat 1
```

We can use <kbd>C-c</kbd> to quit it if we run it in GHCi **without compiling beforehand**:

```
$ ghci Test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> :main            <pressing C-c after a while>
Interrupted.
```

If we compile it and then rerun it in GHCi, it will hang:

```
$ ghc Test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( Test.hs, Test.o )
Linking Test.exe ...

$ ghci Test.hs
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> :main
<hangs indefinitely>
```

Note that you need `-dynamic` if you don't use Windows, as otherwise GHCi will recompile the source file. However, if we use `-fno-omit-yield`, we suddenly can quit again (in Windows).

We can verify that again with another small snippet:

```
Prelude> last xs = case xs of [x] -> x ; (_:ys) -> last ys
Prelude> last $ repeat 1
^CInterrupted
```

As `ghci` doesn't use any optimizations, it also doesn't use `-fomit-yield` (and therefore has `-fno-omit-yield` enabled). Our new variant of `last` doesn't yield the same behaviour as `Prelude.last` as it isn't compiled with `fomit-yield`.

Now that we know *why* this happens, we know that we will experience that behaviour throughout the standard library, as the standard library is compiled with `-fomit-yield`.