# How can I use the Haskell timeout function (in System.Timeout) to halt runaway computations?

Tags: haskell, timeout, infinite-loop, infinite

The timeout function in System.Timeout sometimes fails to halt an infinite computation.

For example,

```hs
timeout 1000 $ print $ length [0..]
```

returns `Nothing` as expected because the timeout interrupts the infinite computation.  But

```hs
timeout 1000 $ print $ length $ cycle [1,2,3]
```

loops forever.

This is on a Mac, using ghc or ghci 8.6.4.

I expect the second example to behave like the first, interrupting the infinite computation after 1 millisecond and returning `Nothing`.  Instead, the second example hangs.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, tight loops that don't allocate memory can't be interrupted with `timeout`. GHC pretends it does preemptive threading, and the facade is very good, but in fact within each OS thread it does cooperative threading. Allocation -- usually a very frequent event in immutable languages -- is the trigger for choosing whether to yield control or not. But GHC is smart enough to be able to optimize this loop into one that doesn't allocate, by observing that `length`'s internal counter can be updated in-place (and `cycle [1,2,3]` allocates as much as it needs in time, it seems).

Comment: See the first entry of [Bugs in GHC](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#bugs-in-ghc). It's a long standing issue, which is not easy to fix without disabling a lot of optimizations.

Comment: @chi Nice! If -fno-omit-yields as suggested in your link works, it seems like it's worth writing a (short) answer suggesting it.

Comment: @DanielWagner It seems rather fragile to me, and it's module-wide instead of expression-wide. Also, Will Ness below found a duplicate, I think.

Comment: Hm. Seems related, though it focuses on interactive, rather than programmatic, ways of stopping infinite loops.

Answer (score 4):

You can use your own, non-sharing implementation of `cycle`:

```
> _Y g = g (_Y g)
_Y :: (t -> t) -> t

> take 10 . _Y $ ([1,2,3] ++)
[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1]
it :: Num a => [a]

> timeout 100000 . print . length . _Y $ ([1,2,3] ++)
Nothing
it :: Maybe ()
(0.11 secs, 152470624 bytes)
```

`_Y` will of course allocate an infinite, growing list, unlike the sharing `cycle` which is equivalent to `fix ([1,2,3] ++)` which creates an actual cyclic list in memory:

```
> timeout 100000 . print . length . fix $ ([1,2,3] ++)
<<<hangs>>>
```

See also:

- [How can I stop infinite evaluation in GHCi?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55188787/849891)